# создать раздел жесткого диска из свободного пространства другого раздела

Tags: ntfs, ext4

Привет. Ситуация такая: есть раздел ntfs, наполовину забитый. Можно ли отделить от него часть пространства и создать новый Ext4 раздел? (не форматируя исходный ntfs раздел, дабы сохранить на нем данные)

Comment: да, можно. Любой адекватный инсталлятор линукса (убунты точно) позволяет это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Gparted такое может. Создайте загрузочною флешку или CD например LinuxMint, там есть Gparted. Но ОСТОРОЖНО! Я бы советовал бекап сделать.